# Access denied when blaming with ToroiseSVN

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

Recently (after installing Windows 7?) I have been experiencing problems when blaming files with TortoiseSVN.
I get an error message like: "Can't open 'c:\temp\tmp.tmp': Access is denied."

If I select the option use text viewer to view blames it works, but that´s a poor view.
I believe it has something to do with timing, because it can work once in a while, but most of the time I get access denied...

Anyone else with this problem any solutions?

Using

TortoiseSVN 1.5.9, Build 15518 - 32 Bit , 2009/02/27 18:34:12
Subversion 1.5.6,

Comment: So it worked for you in the past?  Is there any new anti virus software or other "indexing"/file accessing software running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a bug in Subversion that has been solved. I think that upgrading to a new TortoiseSvn (and you'll also need newer Subversion commandline tools), will fix this.